# How to load a Kaltura video faster

Tags: php, video, kaltura

I am using Kaltura to load a video on my webpage and I am trying to make it load faster.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myvideo.com/partner_id/123?entry_id=0;playerId=daplayer&amp;autoembed=true&amp;width=400&amp;height=220&amp;cache_st=1362074486"></script>
```

Anyway to load it faster? 
Also, what is the difference between using cache_st=1362074486 or 141339990? Does this indicate that I am using the cache or not? As I need to use the cache to reduce the time.

Comment: You could call your ISP and ask for a faster connection. Also, you could call the owner of `myvideo.com` and ask if they could raise their upload speed just for you, it just might be your computers cpu, who can tell?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to find a way to make it faster for any user, not just me. So I am looking for caching the video or any similar solution

Comment: Well, in essence you're downloading a javascript file. This shouldn't cause the issue why your page is loading slowly. And if it does, cache the file to your own server, and link it from there. And `1362074486` is a unix timestamp, it translates to `03/14/2017 @ 2:40am (UTC)` and its highly likely it refers to some sort of cache. But this all together will not help you loading a video faster.

Comment: There are many users using this page, I need to know the difference between cache_st=1362074486 and cache_st= 141339990. Also how to enable the caching for the Kaltura video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loads faster when you remove cache_st from the link